# Unable to locate element within an iframe while the element actually exists

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

No matter how long I wait, it seems selenium can't find the "watch_online" button.

I've tried both by XPath, full XPath, and CSS selector.

I want to get the href link from the "Watch Online" button.

```
import os
import glob
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# Create local browser cache
browser_data_location = "browser_data"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={os.getcwd()}/{browser_data_location}')

i_m_not_a_robot_xpath = '//*[@id="landing"]/div[2]/center/img'
generate_link_xpath = '//*[@id="generater"]/img'
click_to_continue = '//*[@id="showlink"]'
get_download_link = '/html/body/section/div/div/div/center/a'
watch_online = '//*[@id="download-hidden"]/a'

with webdriver.Chrome(options=options, ) as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    time.sleep(2)

    driver.get(
        "https://www.rtilinks.com/?82255aba71=RmwzVDZObDFBdDQvay8zRjhiaStoM004Ymd1T201MnBQelJpdW5oK1UxeGFvbFZUY1FEVXMrY0o2UnhqeGxOOFlwN3JlUElad2h0ek9pQ1ZFZndXSG9UTzA1aFpmTEhoanBVUldEYWwwWVU9")

    # wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, upload_box_css))).send_keys(file)

    wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, i_m_not_a_robot_xpath))).click()
    # time.sleep(1)
    wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, generate_link_xpath))).click()
    wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, click_to_continue))).click()
    # original_window = driver.current_window_handle

    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

    wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, get_download_link))).click()


    time.sleep(2)
    link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, watch_online)
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Watch Online</kbd> is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  - Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://purefiles.in')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Watch Online"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://purefiles.in']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.button.is-success"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='button is-success' and contains(., 'Watch Online')]"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://purefiles.in')]")))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)